# Convert JSON field to ReasonML variant

Tags: json, reason, bucklescript, bs-json

I have a JSON structure that contains a field `period` that can either be an object or a string.
I already have the variant ready in my code, and it's working fine:

```
type period = {
  start: string,
  end_: string,
};

type periodVariant =
  | String(string)
  | Period(period);
```

The problem is when I try to cast the input JSON to the variant type: I simply don't know how to do that.
Here's what my attempt looks like:

```
let periodVariantDecode = (json: Js.Json.t): periodVariant => {
  switch(json) {
  | String(string) => String(Json.Decode.string(string))
  | period => Period(Json.Decode.{
      start: period |> field("start", string),
      end_: period |> field("end", string),
    })
  };
};
```

Now, of course that doesn't work because I'm trying to match something that is still of type `Js.Json.t` against `String` which is part of my `periodVariant`, but I don't know how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what [`either`](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json/blob/master/src/Json_decode.mli#L376-L392) is for. Along with [`map`](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json/blob/master/src/Json_decode.mli#L411-L423) to conveniently "lift" an existing decoder to your variant type.

```rust
type period = {
  start: string,
  end_:  string,
};

type periodVariant =
  | String(string)
  | Period(period);

let period = json =>
  Json.Decode.{
    start: json |> field("start", string),
    end_:  json |> field("end", string),
  };

let periodVariantDecode =
  Json.Decode.(either(
    period |> map(p => Period(p)),
    string |> map(s => String(s))
  ));
```

Comment: Mh that doesn't seem to work... I get `The value period can't be found` on the `period |> map...` line

Comment: `period` is the function defined right above. If you didn't define that, or perhaps made a typo in the name, you'd certainly get that error.

Comment: This is a lot more elegant than my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using bs-json so one way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that `Json.Decode.optional` returns `None` if a decode fails. For your example:

```rust
type period = {
  start: string,
  end_: string,
};

type periodVariant =
  | String(string)
  | Period(period);

let periodVariantDecode = json => {
  let periodString = json |> Json.Decode.(optional(string));
  switch (periodString) {
  | Some(periodString) => String(periodString)
  | None =>
    let periodObj =
      Json.Decode.{
        start: json |> field("start", string),
        end_: json |> field("end", string),
      };
    Period(periodObj);
  };
};
```

That should compile with `periodVariantDecode` being of type `Js.Json.t => periodVariant`. I'm not sure if it's the idiomatic way to go though!

Comment: Just wanted to say that I would recommend @glennsl's answer below over this one!